# generate multivariate cauchy random variable

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, random-variable, cauchy-distribution, elliptical-distribution

How can we generate multivariate random variable in matlab?
Will the set of t distribution with 1 degree of freedom will give multivairate cauchy noise, How to generate?

Comment: See the MO answers at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66307/generating-samples-of-a-multivariate-cauchy-distribution.  Several characterizations at http://www.statlect.com/mcdstu1.htm immediately lead to efficient random generation methods.

Comment: How can we generate for Cauchy random variable, We know that if geometric power for cauchy is σ the power for Gaussian is σ/2cg where cg=1.78. Now if I want to generate Cauchy random variable with given geometric power , How will we generate for both one dimension as well as multi dimension

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/mvtnorm.pdf